# How to migrate all resources and storage from one azure account to another?

Tags: azure, cloud

I have an Azure account with some resources (app services, SQL DB ...) I need to migrate those resources to another Azure account that was created recently. I want the same services with the same conflagrations and names because they serve as API for live apps. is there away to do so?

I am new To Azure and Cloud Services in general so please correct me if you think the question is not clear or understandable

Comment: Not an answer by a tip. This is a very long requested feature. If you want my opinion, open a support ticket. This way you can assure the DNS will be kept to you and all resources will be migrated. (This is the safest way)

Comment: You should be able to do it. Have you seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription?

Comment: I can see under resource group > Move option. did you try that?

Comment: @PankajRawat I do not want to move the resources to another subscription in the same Azure Account, I want to be able to move the resources to a different account that was created by my client

Comment: @GauravMantri I do not want to move the resources to another subscription in the same Azure Account, I want to be able to move the resources to a different account that was created by my client

Comment: Aah, I see. In that case your best bet would be reach out to Azure Support at mentioned by Thiago.